# The math to render a cube?

Tags: vb.net, math, graphics, 3d, render

My friend and I are making a 3d rendering engine from scratch in our VB class at school, but I am not sure how the math to form the cube would work. Given six variables:

```
    rotX
    rotY
    rotZ
    lenX
    lenY
    lenZ
```

Which represent the rotation on x,y,z and the length on x,y,z respectively, what would be the formulas to make the cube? I know that all I have to do is calculate three segments and from those segments just create three parallelograms, so I just need the math to find what the three segments are.
Thanks!

Comment: Depends on how you're doing the rendering. OpenGL performs rotations by multiplying the current matrix with a particular matrix, whose formula is listed [here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glRotate.xml).

Comment: To render, I'm just using the e.Graphics.DrawPolygon function to draw each of the 3 parallelograms derived from the 3 segments where the visible faces intersect.

Comment: By "rendering", I mean, taking a three dimensional point and determining the two dimensional coordinates where that point would be drawn on your screen. Like, if I wanted to plot the point (16,23,42), where would your engine draw the pixel? Have you written the code for that yet?

Comment: No, that's actually what I need help on, now that I think of it. I could probably code the formulas to do the 3d rotation of the cube once I find a formula that actually helps me, but what I am not sure about is how to plot a 3d point onto a 2d surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are 2 basic 3D object representations for both are your data is insufficient.

1. surface representation

   - objects are set of surface polygons/vertexes/...
   - for cube its a set of 8 points + the triangles/quads for 6 faces
2. analytical  representation

   - objects are set of equations describing the object
   - for cube its a intersection of 6 planes

I think you are using option 1 so what you need is:
- position
- orientation
- size

usually an axis aligned cube looks like this:

```
const double a=1.0; //cube size;
double  pnt[8][3]=  //cube points
    {
    +a,-a,+a,
    +a,+a,+a,
    -a,+a,+a,
    -a,-a,+a,
    +a,-a,-a,
    +a,+a,-a,
    -a,+a,-a,
    -a,-a,-a
    };
int     tab[24]=
    {
    0,1,2,3,    // 1st.quad
    7,6,5,4,    // 2nd.quad
    4,5,1,0,    // 3th.quad ...
    5,6,2,1,
    6,7,3,2,
    7,4,0,3
    };
```

well for size and orientation you can apply transformation matrix
or directly recompute points by direction vectors

- so you need to remember position (point) and orientation (3 vectors) and size (scalar)
- all above can be stored in single transformation matrix 4x4
- but if you want the vectors then points will be like this:

P(+a,-a,+a) -> +a*I -a*J +a*K

- where I,J,K are the orientation vectors
- a is cube size
- P(+a,-a,+a) is original axis aligned point in table above

Option 2 is more tricky to implement and unless you really need it (ray-tracing renders) then forget about it.